# What directory is the appsettings.json file copied to on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, restsharp

I am trying to get my Xamarin Forms App to read the appsettings.json config file for setting up RestSharp. I am targeting Android. The appsettings.json file is set to Copy Always in the root of my Android forms project in Visual Studio. I am trying to read in a Factory pattern.

```
 internal class ConfigFactory
{
    public ConfigFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            SetupSimpleConfiguration();
            ReadSimpleConfiguration();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error(e, "Exception Constructing Config Factory");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public RestClient QueryClient { get; private set; }
    public RestClient CommandClient { get; private set; }
    private IConfigurationRoot Config { get; set; }

    private void ReadSimpleConfiguration()
    {
        string val1 = Config["QueryURL"];
        string val2 = Config["CommandURL"];
        QueryClient = new RestClient(val1);
        CommandClient = new RestClient(val2);
    }

    private void SetupSimpleConfiguration()
    {
        var currentDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        Log.Logger.Debug("Enter Simple {@Directory}", currentDirectory);

        Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger.Debug("Leave Simple {@Config}", Config);
    }
}
```

The Exception I keep running into is:

> The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not
>   optional. The physical path is
>   '/data/user/0/com.companyname.SerilogSample/files/appsettings.json'

- No matter what I set currentDirectory to.

Comment: what is the build action set to?

Comment: Build Action None @Jason

Comment: try setting it to Content

Comment: Build Action is now set to Content @Jason.

Comment: And... did you try testing it again?  If it's set to Content I'd expect it to be copied into the root of your app bundle

Comment: @Jason, I ran the app again with a Zebra t20, Galaxy Note 9 and the Android emulator everything gives the exact same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184343/discussion-between-randy-and-jason).

Comment: are you still looking in the files folder?  If it's in the root of your project it will be copied to the root of the app bundle

Comment: I got the same error. IN addition I also received a warning about @(Content) build action is not supported